# Graphing of count of Mysql database column

Tags: c#, mysql, count, bar-chart

I have searched for graphing the count function of sql in c#. I am trying graph a table that counts the entries of each row label and displays the count on a bar graph. Ex:

```
-Foreman    -count(CommentOne)
   Me                3
   you               2
```

I am using this:

> ```
>    chart1.Series.Clear();
>    chart1.Series.Add("Series1");
>    string Query = "select Foreman,count(CommentOne) from database.scaffoldqcdata where Location='" + cb_location + "' Group by Foreman;";
>    MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
>    MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
>    MySqlDataReader myReader;
>    try
>    {
>        conDataBase.Open();
>        myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
>        while (myReader.Read())
>        {
>            this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(myReader.GetString("Foreman"), myReader.GetString("CommentOne"));
>        }
>
>    }
>     catch (Exception ex)
>     {
>         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
>     }
> ```

It is has worked with other queries, but it shows blank when I run this query.

Comment: print out the query after the variable substitution and then run it from the command line to see the results.

Comment: When I run the query in mysql, it creates the table that I want. I think the problem I am having is bringing the column count(Comment) to the c# program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define `CommentOne` in the query using a column alias:

```
select Foreman, count(CommentOne) as CommentOne
from database.scaffoldqcdata
where Location='" + cb_location + "'
Group by Foreman
```

To be honest, I would recommend *not* using that name.  Instead, something like this:

```
select Foreman, count(CommentOne) as NumComments
from database.scaffoldqcdata
where Location='" + cb_location + "'
Group by Foreman
```

And use this name in the charting code:

```
this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(myReader.GetString("Foreman"), myReader.GetString("NumComments"));
```

You might also want to include an `order by`, if you want the results in a particular order.  You shouldn't depend on `group by` to do any particular ordering.

Comment: Thank you for the help, can I declare NumComments in the query? When I added the changes, the chart no longer displayed anything. Do I need to convert NumComments to Int?

Comment: @AnthonyMendez . . . No, the result from the count should be an integer.  Perhaps the problem is with the `where` clause.

Comment: The query that I have works in Mysql, so the 'where' portion should not be a problem. I added 'count(CommentOne) as NumComments' and entered NumComments into the chart. But nothing appears on the graph. The query worked before I put in the count, but it is an important part.

Comment: @AnthonyMendez . . . The mismatched column alias was definitely a problem.  There would seem to be another problem, but nothing pops out to me.  One possibility when code looks right is that the database connection is to the wrong database.

Comment: You were right, when I defined count(CommentOne) as NumComments and got rid of the 'where' clause I was able to fix display the count of each foreman. But I would like to change the count based on the combobox selection, which is why the 'where' was needed.